# Does the timeout value for Python requests refer to first byte received or whole message?

Tags: python

The documentation (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.request) explains the `timeout` value like this:

> timeout (float or tuple) -- (optional) How long to wait for the server
>   to send data before giving up, as a float, or a (connect timeout, read
>   timeout) tuple.

```
response = requests.post(url, data=post_fields, timeout=timeout)
```

Does this mean to wait for the server to send a single byte, or to wait for the server to send a "whole" message? In other words, is a single `timeout` value (not tuple), the timeout for a `read()` call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify `timeout` as a float (not tuple), then this is equivalent to specify a tuple with its components the same value:

```
import requests

try:
    response = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', timeout=0.1)
except requests.exceptions.Timeout as e:
    print(e)
```

If setting `timeout` extremely small (0.001) then we get a `ConnectTimeoutError`:

```
HTTPConnectionPool(host='httpbin.org', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /post (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x039970D0>, 'Connection to httpbin.org timed out. (connect timeout=0.001)'))
```

Increasing this value slightly (0.1) results in a successful connection establishment, but `read()` times out:

```
HTTPConnectionPool(host='httpbin.org', port=80): Read timed out. (read timeout=0.1)
```